# SQLLDR command Error .Dat file not found

Tags: batch-file, sql-loader

I am trying to load few values in Oracle table using SQLLDR command via Command Prompt. I am trying to set a variable to get users put file name which will be accepted in SQLLDR command. I have a Control file (.CTL), a Data file (.txt) however it is throwing error:

`SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file (sqlldrtest.dat)`

even though I have mentioned a .txt file as Data file.

This is first time I am using SQLLDR with a variable. I have successfully used SQLLDR command earlier without any variable.

Please can anyone help me in rectifying this error.

My code for .BAT file is:

```
set /p reportname="Enter Your Report Name: "

SQLLDR USERID=login/password@database CONTROL=%reportname%.CTL, DATA=%reportname%.txt

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma after the CONTROL= and make sure to change your password!

If it still doesn't work, please update your post to show the contents of your control file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the format of your DATA file. Your data file need to have `.dat` extension.

Change the extension of your DATA file from `.txt` to `.dat`

Your command should look like this -

`SQLLDR USERID=login/password@database CONTROL=%reportname%.CTL, DATA=%reportname%.dat`